# Navigation Controller - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to create a food app. Image1 and 2 are what I want my
app to look like. I don't know how to implement it to Swift Xcode.
Right now, I only have 2 view controllers that go back and forth.

Any advice or tip will be appreciated. I am stuck at how to create the
circles. I am thinking about putting the circles into a tableView like
thing, but I am not sure what the best way is to implement this.

I have set up Parse for this project.

Image 1 (list of restaurants):
[Restaurants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9TqO.png)

Image 2 (list of food/drinks):
[Food/Drinks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvc5E.png)

Comment: so your issue is how to create circle in tableview or need suggestion about design and flow

Comment: Create circles in table view like the image. 2 in each row.

Comment: then what you need to do is while setting your image in imageview set  `layer.cornerRadius` , `layer.masksToBounds ` and `layer.borderWidth`
if you need more reference then see my answer below

Comment: Use CollectionView for your first scrren and Table View for your second screen, user imageView.layer.cornerRadius to make imageView like circle.

Answer (score 0):

In tableview delegate where you are setting `YourImageView`

In **swift**

```
YourImageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (YourImageView?.frame.size.height)!/2
YourImageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
YourImageView?.layer.borderWidth = 0
```

In **Objective-C**

```
cell.yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.yourImageView.frame.size.height /2;
cell.yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.yourImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
```